# Replace third value

Tags: notepad++, regex

In Notepad++ I want to replace the third value in column with **0** for all lines.

[image]

Comment: Try reading up on regular expressions first.  I'd recommend [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) as a good starting point.  Then try writing an expression, and if you get stuck, edit your post with a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As it is, 1) we don't know what you don't know, and 2) your sample image is nearly useless, as it doesn't show all of the detail needed to begin creating a working regex.

Comment: Please, don't post sample as image. Post text instead. And show us what you have tried.

Comment: I think you mean to say *the third value in each line*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:\S+\h+){2}\K\S+`
- Replace with: `0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # Beginning of line
  (?:       # start non capture group
    \S+     # 1 or more non space
    \h+     # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  ){2}      # end group, appears twice
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  \S+       # 1 or more non spaces (i.e. the third value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to replace the third value in each *line*.

Assuming that nothing else follows that number and that this is a one-time operation (note that that information is all missing in your question), just use a keyboard macro. That is a bit repetitive but you don't have to spend time learning/experimenting.

Go to the start of the first line, start macro recording.

<kbd>Ctrl-RightArrow</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-RightArrow</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Shift-RightArrow</kbd>0<kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd>

That is: jump to next word twice, select third word, type 0 over it, go to start of line, go one line down.

Now repeat <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-P</kbd> (run keyboard macro) until you're at the bottom of your file.